# Julia REPL in sublime text

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3, julia, sublimerepl

I'm trying to get a Julia REPL working in sublime text. However, I'm having some problems on the julia side while trying to do this. Basically, my embedded julia REPL works, but interactive elements (such as the prompt) are not shown. I'm not interested in using Sublime-IJulia for various reasons.

My REPL does work fine when I run it from xterm.

As far as I know, I need to figure out a way to get Julia to use a basic REPL, when I run it from sublime, however, I'm not sure how I should do this.

Running `Base.active_repl` from xterm gives me the following output:

```
LineEditREPL(
    TTYTerminal("xterm-256color",TTY(open, 0 bytes waiting),TTY(open, 0 bytes waiting),TTY(open, 0 bytes waiting)),
    true,
    "\e[1m\e[32m",
    "\e[1m","\e[1m",
    "\e[1m\e[31m",
    "\e[1m\e[33m",
    false,
    false,
    false,
    true,
    false,
    nothing,
    ModalInterface(TextInterface["Prompt(\"julia> \",...)","Prompt(\"shell> \",...)","Prompt(\"help?> \",...)",HistoryPrompt{REPLHistoryProvider}(REPLHistoryProvider(String["5","exit","exit()","Pkg.status()","Pkg.add(\"ZMQ\")","Pkg.add(\"IJulia\")","Pkg.status()","Pkg.remove(\"IJulia\")","Pkg.rm(\"IJulia\")","Pkg.status()"  …  "import REPL","import Base..REPL","Base.BasicRepl","Base.BasicREPL","Base.REPL","Base.REPL.BasicREPL","Base.active_repl = Base.REPL.BasicREPL()","Base.active_repl","exit()","Base.active_repl"],IOStream(<file .julia_history>),62,-1,IOBuffer(data=Uint8[...], readable=true, writable=true, seekable=true, append=false, size=0, maxsize=Inf, ptr=1, mark=-1),"Prompt(\"julia> \",...)",[:help=>"Prompt(\"help?> \",...)",:shell=>"Prompt(\"shell> \",...)",:julia=>"Prompt(\"julia> \",...)"],[:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia  …  :julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia,:julia]),LatexCompletions(),(anonymous function))]),
    REPLBackendRef(RemoteRef(1,1,0),RemoteRef(1,1,1)))
```

running it from SublimeRepl returns the following error: `ERROR: active_repl not defined`.

So in short, is there some way that allows me to edit the type of REPL that julia starts when I run it from sublime? And if this is possible, which type of REPL do I need to use?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered a workaround awhile back on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/SublimeText/comments/5jtnj7/sublimerepl_is_it_possible_to_mimic_commandline/

In particular:

> Found a (really) hacky solution to see the `julia>` prompts!
>
> In `Preferences > Browse Packages > SublimeREPL/sublimerepl.py`, add
>   these two lines under the `else:` statement of `handle_repl_packet()`:
>
> ```
> if self.repl.name() == 'julia' :
>     self.write_prompt('julia>')
> ```
>
> For reassurance, the method in its entirety will look like this:
>
> ```
> def handle_repl_packet(self, packet):
>         if self.repl.apiv2:
>             for opcode, data in packet:
>                 if opcode == 'output':
>                     self.write(data)
>                 elif opcode == 'prompt':
>                     self.write_prompt(data)
>                 elif opcode == 'highlight':
>                     a, b = data
>                     regions = self._view.get_regions('sublimerepl')
>                     regions.append(sublime.Region(a, b))
>                     self._view.add_regions('sublimerepl', regions, 'invalid',
>                                            '', sublime.DRAW_EMPTY | sublime.DRAW_OUTLINED)
>                 else:
>                     print('SublimeREPL: unknown REPL opcode: ' + opcode)
>         else:
>             if self.repl.name() == 'julia' :
>                 self.write_prompt('julia>')
>             self.write(packet)
> ```
>
> This does fail on the first line - I'll see if I can fix that.
>
> EDIT: I failed to mention that I have previously changed
>   `sublimerepl.py` as described here: [SublimeREPL's Slow
>   Printing/Freezing - A
>   Solution](http://www.xaph.io/2016/07/sublimerepls-slow-printingfreezing_21.html).
>   In my experience, it makes SublimeREPL's printing much faster... and
>   is needed to make this `julia>` fix work as is.

I haven't found a more robust solution since.